# SQL Server Conditional CASE JOIN query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Can someone help me out on Conditional join? 
I want to join on ID and [Name] from both tables and next condition is like

> CASE WHEN a.Count = b.Count THEN a.Rn1 = b.Rn1     WHEN a.Count <>
>   b.Count THEN a.Rn2 = b.Rn2 and a.Rn3 = b.Rn3 END

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test2

CREATE TABLE #Test1 (ID int, [name] varchar(50),[Count] int, Rn1 int, Rn2 int, Rn3 int)
CREATE TABLE #Test2 (ID int, [name] varchar(50),[Count] int, Rn1 int, Rn2 int, Rn3 int)

Insert Into #Test1 
Values 
 (123123,'Hours',6,1,1,1)
,(123123,'Hours',6,2,1,2)
,(123123,'Hours',6,3,2,1)
,(123123,'Hours',6,4,3,1)
,(123123,'Hours',6,5,3,2)
,(123123,'Hours',6,6,4,1)
,(123123,'NI1',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,'NI2',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,'PAY',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,'Teachers1',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,'Teachers2',1,1,1,1)

,(123124,N'Hours',5,1,1,1)
,(123124,N'Hours',5,2,2,1)
,(123124,N'Hours',5,3,3,1)
,(123124,N'Hours',5,4,3,2)
,(123124,N'Hours',5,5,4,1)
,(123124,N'NI1',1,1,1,1)
,(123124,N'NI2',1,1,1,1)
,(123124,N'PAY',1,1,1,1)

--SELECT * FROM #Test1 

Insert Into #Test2
Values (123123,N'Hours',6,1,1,1)
,(123123,N'Hours',6,2,1,2)
,(123123,N'Hours',6,3,2,1)
,(123123,N'Hours',6,4,3,1)
,(123123,N'Hours',6,5,3,2)
,(123123,N'Hours',6,6,4,1)
,(123123,N'NI1',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,N'NI2',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,N'PAY',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,N'Teachers1',1,1,1,1)
,(123123,N'Teachers2',1,1,1,1)

,(123124,N'Hours',6,1,1,1)
,(123124,N'Hours',6,2,2,1)
,(123124,N'Hours',6,3,3,1)
,(123124,N'Hours',6,4,3,2)
,(123124,N'Hours',6,5,3,3)
,(123124,N'Hours',6,6,4,1)
,(123124,N'NI1',1,1,1,1)
,(123124,N'NI2',1,1,1,1)
,(123124,N'PAY',1,1,1,1)

--SELECT * FROM #Test2
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicates of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows `THEN` and `ELSE`) always has to be a value, not another logical expression.  Without seeing your entire query, I can suggest the following refactor:

```
WHERE
    (a.Count = b.Count AND a.Rn1 = b.Rn1) OR
    (a.Count <> b.Count AND a.Rn2 = b.Rn2 AND a.Rn3 = b.Rn3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try to implement in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a `CASE` expression like a `CASE` statement. A `CASE` **expression** returns a scalar value not a boolean result. So, for example the following syntax is valid:

```
WHERE CASE [Column] WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END = OtherColumn;
```

This is because the `CASE` expression returns the scalar value `1` or `2`. The following statement, would be invalid:

```
WHERE CASE [Column] WHEN 'A' THEN OtherColumn = 1 ELSE OtherColumn = 2 END;
```

A `CASE` in a `WHERE` in T-SQL needs to be part of a boolean expression (`{CASE expression} {=|!=|>|<|etc} {Expression}`), not return one.

Using a `CASE` expression in a `WHERE` clause, however, makes your query non-SARGable, you are far better off righting out some boolean logic. For what yoiu have that would likely be:

```
WHERE (A.[Count] = b.[Count]
  AND  A.RN1 = B.RN1)
   OR (A.[Count] != b.[Count]
  AND  A.RN2 = B.RN2
  AND  A.RN3 = B.RN3);
```

Comment: he is actually trying to do a  join on the two tables, so the logic shoujld be made on the 'ON' section. Although I think he is getting this join logic wrong.

Comment: @MEdwin, you are right I am trying to create same logic on Join clause

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do something like this with CASE expressions:

```
WHERE 1 = (CASE WHEN a.Count = b.Count THEN  CASE WHEN a.Rn1 = b.Rn1 THEN 1 END 
                WHEN a.Count <> b.Count THEN CASE WHEN a.Rn2 = b.Rn2 and a.Rn3 = b.Rn3 THEN 1 END
           END)
```

That's a literal translation of the original request without any optimization.